# What exactly qualifies as a 'Tensor' in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

I am new to TensorFlow and just went through the eager execution tutorial and came across the tf.decode_csv function. Not knowing about it, I read the documentation.  https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/decode_csv

I don't really understand it.

The documentation says 'records: A Tensor of type string.' 
**So, my question is: What qualifies as a 'Tensor'?**

I tried the following code:

```
dec_res = tf.decode_csv('0.1,0.2,0.3', [[0.0], [0.0], [0.0]])
print(dec_res, type(dec_res))



l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
r = tf.reshape(l, [9,-1])
print(l, type(l))
print(r, type(r))
```

So the list `dec_res` contains tf.tensor objects. That seems reasonable to me. But is an ordinary string also a 'Tensor' according to the documentation?

Then I tried something else with the `tf.reshape` function. In the documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape it says that 'tensor: A Tensor.' So, `l` is supposed to be a tensor. But it is not of type `tf.tensor` but simply a python `list`. This is confusing.

Then the documentation says

> Returns:
>
> A Tensor. Has the same type as tensor.

But the type of `l` is `list` where the type of `r` is `tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor`. So the types are not the same.

Then I thought that TensorFlow is very generous with things being a tensor. So I tried:

```
class car(object):
def __init__(self, color):
    self.color = color


red_car = car('red')
#test_reshape = tf.reshape(red_car, [1, -1])
print(red_car.color) # to check, that red_car exists.
```

Now, the line in comments results in an error.

So, can anyone help me to find out, what qualifies as a 'Tensor'?

P.S.: I tried to read the source code of `tf.reshape` as given in the documentation

> Defined in tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py.

But this file does not exist in the Github repo. Does anyone know how to read it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/tensors

> TensorFlow, as the name indicates, is a framework to define and run
>   computations involving tensors. A tensor is a generalization of
>   vectors and matrices to potentially higher dimensions. Internally,
>   TensorFlow represents tensors as n-dimensional arrays of base
>   datatypes.

What you are observing commes from the fact that tensorflow operations (like reshape) can be built from various python types using the function tf.convert_to_tensor:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor

> All standard Python op constructors apply this function to each of
>   their Tensor-valued inputs, which allows those ops to accept numpy
>   arrays, Python lists, and scalars in addition to Tensor objects

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I have been looking for. Do you perhaps know how to read the file tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py.?

Comment: `print tf.__file__`